# How to connect Ardunio ESP8266 wifi server with asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I want to develop asp.net application then can send data to ESP8266 which will be act as to show that message. 
What I have done, I have fully function Esp8266 board which show Ip address it is connect and any message which can be send from this web page which is coded with it.

here is the code

```
// Use the MD_MAX72XX library to scroll text on the display
// received through the ESP8266 WiFi interface.
//
// Demonstrates the use of the callback function to control what
// is scrolled on the display text. User can enter text through
// a web browser and this will display as a scrolling message on
// the display.
//
// IP address for the ESP8266 is displayed on the scrolling display
// after startup initialization and connected to the WiFi network.
//
// Connections for ESP8266 hardware SPI are:
// Vcc       3v3     LED matrices seem to work at 3.3V 
// GND       GND     GND
// DIN        D7     HSPID or HMOSI
// CS or LD   D8     HSPICS or HCS
// CLK        D5     CLK or HCLK
//

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <MD_MAX72xx.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define PRINT_CALLBACK  0
#define DEBUG 0
#define LED_HEARTBEAT 0

#if DEBUG
#define PRINT(s, v) { Serial.print(F(s)); Serial.print(v); }
#define PRINTS(s)   { Serial.print(F(s)); }
#else
#define PRINT(s, v)
#define PRINTS(s)
#endif


#if LED_HEARTBEAT
#define HB_LED  D2
#define HB_LED_TIME 500 // in milliseconds
#endif

// Define the number of devices we have in the chain and the hardware interface
// NOTE: These pin numbers will probably not work with your hardware and may
// need to be adapted
#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::FC16_HW
#define MAX_DEVICES 4

#define CLK_PIN   14 // or SCK
#define DATA_PIN  13 // or MOSI
#define CS_PIN    15 // or SS

// SPI hardware interface
MD_MAX72XX mx = MD_MAX72XX(HARDWARE_TYPE, CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);
// Arbitrary pins
//MD_MAX72XX mx = MD_MAX72XX(HARDWARE_TYPE, DATA_PIN, CLK_PIN, CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);

// WiFi login parameters - network name and password
const char* ssid = "Honor 7C";
const char* password = "fawaz@123";

// WiFi Server object and parameters
WiFiServer server(80);

// Global message buffers shared by Wifi and Scrolling functions
const uint8_t MESG_SIZE = 255;
const uint8_t CHAR_SPACING = 1;
const uint8_t SCROLL_DELAY = 200;

char curMessage[MESG_SIZE];
char newMessage[MESG_SIZE];
bool newMessageAvailable = false;

const char WebResponse[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n";

const char WebPage[] =
"<!DOCTYPE html>" \
"<html>" \
"<head>" \
"<title>MajicDesigns Test Page</title>" \

"<script>" \
"strLine = \"\";" \

"function SendText()" \
"{" \
"  nocache = \"/&nocache=\" + Math.random() * 1000000;" \
"  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();" \
"  strLine = \"&Message=\" + document.getElementById(\"txt_form\").Message.value;" \
"  request.open(\"GET\", strLine + nocache, true);" \
"  request.send(null);" \
"}" \
"</script>" \
"</head>" \

"<body>" \
"<p><b>MD_MAX72xx set message</b></p>" \

"<form id=\"txt_form\" name=\"frmText\">" \
"<label>Msg:<input type=\"text\" name=\"Message\" maxlength=\"255\"></label><br><br>" \
"</form>" \
"<br>" \
"<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Send Text\" onclick=\"SendText()\">" \
"</body>" \
"</html>";

const char *err2Str(wl_status_t code)
{
  switch (code)
  {
  case WL_IDLE_STATUS:    return("IDLE");           break; // WiFi is in process of changing between statuses
  case WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL:  return("NO_SSID_AVAIL");  break; // case configured SSID cannot be reached
  case WL_CONNECTED:      return("CONNECTED");      break; // successful connection is established
  case WL_CONNECT_FAILED: return("CONNECT_FAILED"); break; // password is incorrect
  case WL_DISCONNECTED:   return("CONNECT_FAILED"); break; // module is not configured in station mode
  default: return("??");
  }
}

uint8_t htoi(char c)
{
  c = toupper(c);
  if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) return(c - '0');
  if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'F')) return(c - 'A' + 0xa);
  return(0);
}

boolean getText(char *szMesg, char *psz, uint8_t len)
{
  boolean isValid = false;  // text received flag
  char *pStart, *pEnd;      // pointer to start and end of text

  // get pointer to the beginning of the text
  pStart = strstr(szMesg, "/&Message=");

  if (pStart != NULL)
  {
    pStart += 10;  // skip to start of data
    pEnd = strstr(pStart, "/&");

    if (pEnd != NULL)
    {
      while (pStart != pEnd)
      {
        if ((*pStart == '%') && isdigit(*(pStart+1)))
        {
          // replace %xx hex code with the ASCII character
          char c = 0;
          pStart++;
          c += (htoi(*pStart++) << 4);
          c += htoi(*pStart++);
          *psz++ = c;
        }
        else
          *psz++ = *pStart++;
      }

      *psz = '\0'; // terminate the string
      isValid = true;
    }
  }

  return(isValid);
}

void handleWiFi(void)
{
  static enum { S_IDLE, S_WAIT_CONN, S_READ, S_EXTRACT, S_RESPONSE, S_DISCONN } state = S_IDLE;
  static char szBuf[1024];
  static uint16_t idxBuf = 0;
  static WiFiClient client;
  static uint32_t timeStart;

  switch (state)
  {
  case S_IDLE:   // initialize
    PRINTS("\nS_IDLE");
    idxBuf = 0;
    state = S_WAIT_CONN;
    break;

  case S_WAIT_CONN:   // waiting for connection
    {
      client = server.available();
      if (!client) break;
      if (!client.connected()) break;

#if DEBUG
      char szTxt[20];
      sprintf(szTxt, "%03d:%03d:%03d:%03d", client.remoteIP()[0], client.remoteIP()[1], client.remoteIP()[2], client.remoteIP()[3]);
      PRINT("\nNew client @ ", szTxt);
#endif

      timeStart = millis();
      state = S_READ;
    }
    break;

  case S_READ: // get the first line of data
    PRINTS("\nS_READ");
    while (client.available())
    {
      char c = client.read();
      if ((c == '\r') || (c == '\n'))
      {
        szBuf[idxBuf] = '\0';
        client.flush();
        PRINT("\nRecv: ", szBuf);
        state = S_EXTRACT;
      }
      else
        szBuf[idxBuf++] = (char)c;
    }
    if (millis() - timeStart > 1000)
    {
      PRINTS("\nWait timeout");
      state = S_DISCONN;
    }
    break;


  case S_EXTRACT: // extract data
    PRINTS("\nS_EXTRACT");
    // Extract the string from the message if there is one
    newMessageAvailable = getText(szBuf, newMessage, MESG_SIZE);
    PRINT("\nNew Msg: ", newMessage);
    state = S_RESPONSE;
    break;

  case S_RESPONSE: // send the response to the client
    PRINTS("\nS_RESPONSE");
    // Return the response to the client (web page)
    client.print(WebResponse);
    client.print(WebPage);
    state = S_DISCONN;
    break;

  case S_DISCONN: // disconnect client
    PRINTS("\nS_DISCONN");
    client.flush();
    client.stop();
    state = S_IDLE;
    break;

  default:  state = S_IDLE;
  }
}

void scrollDataSink(uint8_t dev, MD_MAX72XX::transformType_t t, uint8_t col)
// Callback function for data that is being scrolled off the display
{
#if PRINT_CALLBACK
  Serial.print("\n cb ");
  Serial.print(dev);
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.println(col);
#endif
}

uint8_t scrollDataSource(uint8_t dev, MD_MAX72XX::transformType_t t)
// Callback function for data that is required for scrolling into the display
{
  static enum { S_IDLE, S_NEXT_CHAR, S_SHOW_CHAR, S_SHOW_SPACE } state = S_IDLE;
  static char *p;
  static uint16_t curLen, showLen;
  static uint8_t  cBuf[8];
  uint8_t colData = 0;

  // finite state machine to control what we do on the callback
  switch (state)
  {
  case S_IDLE: // reset the message pointer and check for new message to load
    PRINTS("\nS_IDLE");
    p = curMessage;      // reset the pointer to start of message
    if (newMessageAvailable)  // there is a new message waiting
    {
      strcpy(curMessage, newMessage); // copy it in
      newMessageAvailable = false;
    }
    state = S_NEXT_CHAR;
    break;

  case S_NEXT_CHAR: // Load the next character from the font table
    PRINTS("\nS_NEXT_CHAR");
    if (*p == '\0')
      state = S_IDLE;
    else
    {
      showLen = mx.getChar(*p++, sizeof(cBuf) / sizeof(cBuf[0]), cBuf);
      curLen = 0;
      state = S_SHOW_CHAR;
    }
    break;

  case S_SHOW_CHAR: // display the next part of the character
    PRINTS("\nS_SHOW_CHAR");
    colData = cBuf[curLen++];
    if (curLen < showLen)
      break;

    // set up the inter character spacing
    showLen = (*p != '\0' ? CHAR_SPACING : (MAX_DEVICES*COL_SIZE)/2);
    curLen = 0;
    state = S_SHOW_SPACE;
    // fall through

  case S_SHOW_SPACE:  // display inter-character spacing (blank column)
    PRINT("\nS_ICSPACE: ", curLen);
    PRINT("/", showLen);
    curLen++;
    if (curLen == showLen)
      state = S_NEXT_CHAR;
    break;

  default:
    state = S_IDLE;
  }

  return(colData);
}

void scrollText(void)
{
  static uint32_t  prevTime = 0;

  // Is it time to scroll the text?
  if (millis() - prevTime >= SCROLL_DELAY)
  {
    mx.transform(MD_MAX72XX::TSL);  // scroll along - the callback will load all the data
    prevTime = millis();      // starting point for next time
  }
}

void setup()
{
#if DEBUG
  Serial.begin(115200);
  PRINTS("\n[MD_MAX72XX WiFi Message Display]\nType a message for the scrolling display from your internet browser");
#endif

#if LED_HEARTBEAT
  pinMode(HB_LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(HB_LED, LOW);
#endif

  // Display initialization
  mx.begin();
  mx.setShiftDataInCallback(scrollDataSource);
  mx.setShiftDataOutCallback(scrollDataSink);

  curMessage[0] = newMessage[0] = '\0';

  // Connect to and initialize WiFi network
  PRINT("\nConnecting to ", ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    PRINT("\n", err2Str(WiFi.status()));
    delay(500);
  }
  PRINTS("\nWiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  PRINTS("\nServer started");

  // Set up first message as the IP address
  sprintf(curMessage, "%03d:%03d:%03d:%03d", WiFi.localIP()[0], WiFi.localIP()[1], WiFi.localIP()[2], WiFi.localIP()[3]);
  PRINT("\nAssigned IP ", curMessage);
}

void loop()
{
//#if LED_HEARTBEAT
//  static uint32_t timeLast = 0;
//
//  if (millis() - timeLast >= HB_LED_TIME)
//  {
//    digitalWrite(HB_LED, digitalRead(HB_LED) == LOW ? HIGH : LOW);
//    timeLast = millis();
//  }
//#endif

  handleWiFi();
  scrollText();
}
```

upto here every thing is fine,

board showing this ip 192.168.43.133
I have created asp.net web form application ,

```
<%@ Page  Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="QueueForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.QueueForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MajicDesigns Test Page</title>
    <script>
        strLine = "";
        function SendText() {
            nocache = "/&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000;
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            strLine ="http://192.168.43.133/"+"&Message=" + document.getElementById("txt_form").Message.value;
            request.open("GET", strLine + nocache, true); request.send(null);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="txt_form" name="frmText">
        <label>
            Msg:
    <input type="text" name="Message" maxlength="255">
        </label>
        <br>
        <br>
    </form>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Text" onclick="SendText()"></body></html>
```

in this case board show nothing,

but when I paste ip of board in browser and then click on send text button , board start showing message?

What I can do connect these two, and can show any message from my application?

Comment: Do you have the documentation on the Adrunio?  I can't tell the format of the Adrunio input.  It looks like the Adrunio want simple text and you are sending an XmlHttpRequest.  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare working message with your web application.

Comment: If you look at Adrunio code there is simple webpage code, when server is running then we can send any text from that web page, and that text will display on board, that is done through httprequest.

Comment: That code is not posted.  I think the Adrunio code is taking a string input and formatting the string to a httprequest.  If you want to send a request than you need to modify the Adrunio to accept either a string or a request.

Comment: here is code I was talking about.
`
const char WebPage[] =
"<!DOCTYPE html>" \
"<html>" \
"<head>" \
"<title>MajicDesigns Test Page</title>" \

"<script>" \
"strLine = \"\";" \

"function SendText()" \
"{" \
"  nocache = \"/&nocache=\" + Math.random() * 1000000;" \
"  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();" \
"  strLine = \"&Message=\" + document.getElementById(\"txt_form\").Message.value;" \
"  request.open(\"GET\", strLine + nocache, true);" \
"  request.send(null);" \
"}" \
"</script>" \
"</head>" \
`

Comment: Can you please scroll adrunio code chunk you can see detail of code?